# Why I get exec failed: container_linux.go:380 when I go inside Kubernetes pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I started learning about Kubernetes and I installed minikube and kubectl on Windows 7.

After that I created a pod with command:

```
kubectl run firstpod --image=nginx
```

And everything is fine:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Now I want to go inside the pod with this command: `kubectl exec -it firstpod -- /bin/bash` but it's not working and I have this error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container
 process caused: exec: "C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe": stat C:/Program
Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe: no such file or directory: unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
```

How can I resolve this problem?

And another question is about this `firstpod` pod. With this command `kubectl describe pod firstpod` I can see information about the pod:

```
Name:         firstpod
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/192.168.99.100
Start Time:   Mon, 08 Nov 2021 16:39:07 +0200
Labels:       run=firstpod
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           172.17.0.3
IPs:
  IP:  172.17.0.3
Containers:
  firstpod:
    Container ID:   docker://59f89dad2ddd6b93ac4aceb2cc0c9082f4ca42620962e4e692e3d6bcb47d4a9e
    Image:          nginx
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://nginx@sha256:644a70516a26004c97d0d85c7fe1d0c3a67ea8ab7ddf4aff193d9f301670cf36
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 08 Nov 2021 16:39:14 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-9b8mx (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-9b8mx:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  32m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/firstpod to minikube
  Normal  Pulling    32m   kubelet            Pulling image "nginx"
  Normal  Pulled     32m   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx" in 3.677130128s
  Normal  Created    31m   kubelet            Created container firstpod
  Normal  Started    31m   kubelet            Started container firstpod
```

So I can see it is a docker container id and it is started, also there is the image, but if I do `docker images` or `docker ps` there is nothing. Where are these images and container? Thank you!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAcMP.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One error for certain is gitbash adding Windows the path. You can disable that with a double slash:

```
kubectl exec -it firstpod -- //bin/bash
```

This command will only work if you have bash in the image. If you don't, you'll need to pick a different command to run, e.g. `/bin/sh`. Some images are distroless or based on scratch to explicitly not include things like shells, which will prevent you from running commands like this (intentionally, for security).

Comment: Why is kubectl appending local path to server instructions, that doesn't make sense at all. What was their intention with this...

Comment: @DanielW. it's not kubectl, it's gitbash. Presumably to make local shell scripts work on the Windows side.

Comment: Thank you @BMitch! Now it's working, but if I do `docker images` or `docker ps` why I can't see this nginx?

Comment: @Elvis is your kubernetes CRI set to the docker shim, containerd, or something else?

Comment: @BMitch, I don't know, I'm very new to kubernetes. I see that when I create the first pod, it pulls the nginx image, and start a docker container and I thought I can see this docker image and container using docker images and docker ps commands.

Comment: @Elvis if you're running kubernetes commands, stay with kubectl. Most likely you're on the containerd CRI, and k8s is in a different namespace from docker in containerd.